# ContentControl's formatting leaks outside control

Tags: c#, vsto, word-2007

I'm developing application level add-in plugin to Word 2007. Unlucky I've encountered minor problem with styling dynamically added content:

I've created Content control, and changed it's style with following code:

```
PlainTextContentControl plainTextControl =
   extendedDocument.Controls.AddPlainTextContentControl(
   currentDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.Range,"ptcc1");

plainTextControl.Text = "hello world";

plainTextControl.Range.Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = (WdColor)ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.LightGray);
plainTextControl.Range.Borders.Enable = (int)WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle;
plainTextControl.LockContents = true;
```

It works - inserted text control has border and gray background, but when i type text just after inserted element this style persist - newly typed characters are bordered and with background color as well. How to limit formatting changes to ContentControl only?

Answer (score 0):

```
var document = Globals.ThisDocument.InnerObject;

PlainTextContentControl plainTextControl = Controls.AddPlainTextContentControl(
document.ActiveWindow.Selection.Range, "ptcc1");
```

works for me in word 2010 - so no guarantee! :)

cheerz